# How insert FeatureCollection to postgis?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, postgis, geopandas

I've created table scheme with sqlalchemy.\

```
class Calculation(Base):
    __tablename__ = "calculations"

    calculation_id = sa.Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), default=uuid4, primary_key=True)
    tle = sa.Column(sa.String, nullable=False)
    shape = sa.Column(Geometry(from_text="ST_GeomFromGeoJSON", srid=4326), nullable=False)
```

And I have geojson with multiple [features](https://pastebin.com/RLUDZ91q).

I tried different ways for convert geojson to dataframe, dataseries and insert to database. Not working.

For example:

```
js = '''
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
...
...
'''

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(js["features"])
    calc = Calculation(tle='1', shape=func.ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(gs))

    db.add(sat)
    db.commit()
```

It takes error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'GeoDataFrame'
```

Comment: the the `json` is nested then what kind of dataframe are you expecting ?

Comment: See [https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/142391/storing-geojson-featurecollection-to-postgresql-with-postgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/142391/storing-geojson-featurecollection-to-postgresql-with-postgis) it should help you to solve your issue.